# No table view after CRUD Scaffolding

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently learning about Ruby on Rails, following this particular tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmyvWz5TUWg&t=2625s

After execute the command `rails g scaffold friends name:string email:string phone:string` followed by `rails db:migrate` I ended up with a CRUD structure to that simple friend model (name, email and phone all strings).

Everything is good and all works fine except when i go to `http://localhost:3000/friends` and the list of friends is showed in a weird way! I was expecting a table where each row is an friend, instead of that i end up with a vertical structure where each friend is displayed vertically...

**index.html.erb**

```
<p style="color: green"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Friends</h1>

<div id="friends">
  <% @friends.each do |friend| %>
    <%= render friend %>
    <p>
      <%= link_to "Show this friend", friend %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
</div>

<%= link_to "New friend", new_friend_path %>
```

**_friend.html.erb**

```
<div id="<%= dom_id friend %>">
  <p>
    <strong>Name:</strong>
    <%= friend.name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Email:</strong>
    <%= friend.email %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Phone:</strong>
    <%= friend.phone %>
  </p>

</div>
```

Illustrative image:
[image]

I believe that i have something with wrong configuration but can't find out what.

All source code: https://github.com/Paul-Bob/RailsFriends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and came across your question while looking for a solution. It appears that the Rails team made a decision to change the index template, though I don't know what the reason was. Possibly because a lot of people are going to want to define their own specific way for tables to be laid out.

**Custom scaffolding templates**

If you do want to use scaffolding, and don't want to have to change the generated index each time, you can create your own custom scaffolding templates.

**Explanation of custom templates**

This guy does a good job of explaining how to do this:

https://web-crunch.com/posts/how-to-create-custom-scaffold-templates-in-ruby-on-rails

**Default templates**

You may want to look at the default templates as a reference. You can find these in your Rails installation. I'm running on Windows, so for me, they are found in:

C:\Ruby31-x64\lib\ruby\gems\3.1.0\gems\railties-7.0.3.1\lib\rails\generators\erb\scaffold\templates

The folder structure will be similar on every platform.

**Default templates on GitHub**

You can also look at the source on GitHub. Found here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/main/railties/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/templates

If you look at "index.html.erb.tt" specifically, you can go into the history and look at where it changed from being rendered as a table. It looks like the change to "modernize" the template happened 4 Feb 2021. If you look at the version *before* that, you should have something that can generate a table.

**Another tutorial**

Here's another example, which generates templates that use Bootstrap and Simple Form. I found it quite a good fit as I was already using Bootstrap and just had to add Simple Form to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'simple_form'
```

**Regenerating scaffold**

After getting the templates from the above example, I wanted to use them to regenerate my views. This can be done with:

```
rails g erb:scaffold friend first_name last_name phone twitter
```

**Disclaimer**

I literally looked at Ruby for the first time yesterday, so this answer may need some editing. :)

Comment: Your answer is a gem! I was following a tutorial for an older version of Rails and got disturbed by that… You saved me a lot of time searching!
One person did complain about that change by the way:
https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/164c2f625742da95407c44c70a381e2c80e4e118#commitcomment-50792286

Answer (score 2):

everything in your case is OK with backend - the only part that needs refinement is the frontend presentation of friends. I'm not sure what version of rails you are using - and what configuration settings - thus sometimes scaffolding can generate a table - sometimes just a simple view like yours.

In order to display friends in a table you have to implement a HTML table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @friends.each do |friend| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= friend.name %></td>
        <td><%= friend.email %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', friend %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_friend_path(friend) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', friend, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm using Rails 7.0.2.2, thanks for the code but i want to make it to be like that by default, otherwise I need to change it manually after every scaffolding

Comment: I just downgraded to version 6.0.2 and everything works just i expected, maybe in version 7.0.2.2 they changed the default, its a recent version and some gems are not working at 100% that's why i decided to downgrade at least while I'm learning it

Comment: Good to hear you've managed to solve it - however I'd try the most up-to-date rails 6 version which is 6.1.4.6 - you can see it here https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions